# Returning Max date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I'm trying to return the Max Dates of the input dates.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getMaxMonthDate]
    @from datetime,
    @to datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT MAX(DAY(ds.datum)) AS DayMax,
           MONTH(ds.datum) AS MonthMax,
           YEAR(ds.datum) AS YearMax,
           CAST(CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(ds.datum)) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(ds.datum)) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, MAX(DAY(ds.datum))) AS DATETIME) AS DateMax

    FROM QR_DS022s ds
    WHERE ds.datum >= @from AND ds.datum <= @to
    GROUP BY MONTH(ds.datum), YEAR(ds.datum), ds.datum
END
```

For example when I'm typing

`@from='2014-01-01'` and `@to='2014-04-01'` then the result of the query is as follows:

```
DayMax | MonthMax | YearMax | DateMax
========================================
  31   |    1     |   2014  | 2014-01-31
  28   |    2     |   2014  | 2014-02-28
  31   |    3     |   2014  | 2014-03-31
  01   |    4     |   2014  | 2014-04-01
```

Currently I'm getting all dates but I want only the last date of the month. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant table ddl and some dml for sample data?

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. It is generally preferable to play with date/time data using the appropriate functions, e.g. `DATEFROMPARTS`, rather than converting to/from strings. If you do use strings then you should explicitly specify the format lest a change in settings, e.g. `SET LANGUAGE`, causes some consternation.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra clause to the `WHERE`, depending on sql version the logic changes

For SQL2012-onwards use [`EOMONTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx)

```
...
WHERE ds.datum >= @from AND ds.datum <= @to
AND EOMONTH(ds.datum) = ds.datum
...
```

Pre-SQL2012 add one to the day and check its the same month

```
...
WHERE ds.datum >= @from AND ds.datum <= @to
AND MONTH(DATEADD(day,1,ds.datum)) != MONTH(ds.datum)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Take ds.datum off the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the maximum day using the methods in your question, you are going to need several changes.  For instance, your `@to` value would not return 30 for '2014-04-01', because you are only considering one day.

I think the following would work, using your approach:

```
SELECT MAX(DAY(ds.datum)) AS DayMax,
       MONTH(ds.datum) AS MonthMax,
       YEAR(ds.datum) AS YearMax,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(ds.datum), 120) as DateMax
FROM QR_DS022s ds
WHERE ds.datum >= @from AND
      ds.datum <= DATEADD(month, 1, @to)
GROUP BY MONTH(ds.datum), YEAR(ds.datum)
HAVING (YEAR(ds.datum) < YEAR(@to) OR MONTH(ds.datum <= MONTH(@to));
```

Notes on the changes:

- Just use the built-in `convert()` to get the format you want.
- Never use `varchar` without a length in SQL Server.  The default length varies by context and bugs relating to length are hard to find.
- This adds a month to be sure the final day is considered by the query.
- The `HAVING` clause removes the extra month.

And, in SQL Server 2012+, this is much simpler with the built-in `EOMONTH()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified my answer to fit your needs.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Jagg DATE)
DECLARE @startdate DATE
SET @startdate = '1/1/2014'
WHILE (@startdate <= '4/1/2014')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @temp(Jagg)
VALUES ((CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@startdate)+1,0)-1 AS DATE)))
SET @startdate = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@startdate)
END
SELECT * FROM @temp
```

Comment: GETDATE() is of the currently month isn't it?

Comment: You are correct. I should read questions and examples more thoroughly.

Comment: @yuro I've modified my answer for you. Maybe this will be useful.